# SELECT and WHERE in android (SQlite)

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to search if there are exact course_no, semester ,and year value in the table.
I problem is that I can only filter course_no.

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_COURSE, CourseItemDataSource.allColumns, DatabaseHelper.KEY_COURSE_COURSE_NO + "=?", new String[] { notiItem.getCourseNo() }, null, null, null);
```

When I tried to add other filter it doesn't seems to work

[Edited] Sorry for being not informative, the problem is that when I pass the below code filter don't work. Note that notiItem.getCourseNo() and notiItem.getYear() is a String.

The following column in the table is a TEXT.

[image: Table]

```
 Cursor cursor = database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_COURSE, CourseItemDataSource.allColumns, DatabaseHelper.KEY_COURSE_COURSE_NO + "=? AND "+DatabaseHelper.KEY_COURSE_YEAR+"=?", new String[] { notiItem.getCourseNo() ,notiItem.getYear()}, null, null, null);
```

This is code the method I tried

```
 public CourseItem searchToCourse(NotificationItem notiItem){
      /**Check if exact course_no, semester, year of notiItem exist in Course Table
       * return null if not found
       * 
       */
      String [] columns = new String[]{ "*"};
      Cursor cursor = database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_COURSE, CourseItemDataSource.allColumns, DatabaseHelper.KEY_COURSE_COURSE_NO + "=?", new String[] { notiItem.getCourseNo() }, null, null, null);

      Log.i("DATA SOURCE", "AFTER QUERY ");
      if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
      }

      CourseItem courseItem = CourseItemDataSource.cursorToCourseItem(cursor);
      return courseItem;
  }
```

How can I search multiple column at a time??

Comment: In ` Cursor cursor = database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_COURSE, CourseItemDataSource.allColumns, DatabaseHelper.KEY_COURSE_COURSE_NO + "=? AND "+DatabaseHelper.KEY_COURSE_YEAR+"=?", new String[] { notiItem.getCourseNo() ,notiItem.get}, null, null, null);` what is `notiItem.get` ? Is `get` a function/method, a field in the class, ... ?

Comment: `it doesn't seems to work` - arrrrgggghhhh I could scream.  This happens about 32,543,945 times every day on this site (I counted them).  What does this mean, exactly?  You get the wrong result?  You don't get any result?  Your app crashes? Your trousers catch fire?  The sun stops shining?

Comment: @Simon, I sincerely agree with your frustration, but it has been my experience that "it doesn't seem to work" means "I get nothing back" or "it doesn't do anything (that I can see)" (depending on the situation).

In addition, we do not know the contents of the database columns, so we don't know if this is an issue of improper query string. If one of the column names has a space, THAT could be the issue. Example: `course no = ? AND course year = ?`

Comment: An advice unrelated to your question: if you want to select all columns, you don't need to pass a array of all columns name, you can simply pass `null` as a second argument in your `query` method.

Comment: Is the year stored as a string?